# Convert $\int_0^1dx \int_0^{x^2}f(x,y) dy $ to polar integration

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

Converting $\int_0^1dx \int_0^{x^2}f(x,y) dy $ to polar coordinates:

$(r \cos\theta)^2 = r \sin\theta$, so $ r= tg\theta\sec\theta$, then the result is,
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4} d\theta \int_0^{tg\theta\sec\theta} f(r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta) rdr $$

please teach me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The bounds for the polar integral in the question are for $0\le r\le\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)$:

[image]

However, Koro's comment to Ross Millikan's answer suggests $\sec(\theta)\tan(\theta)\le r\le\sec(\theta)$:

[image]

which seems like the region you really want, given limits of the Cartesian integral.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you don't have $y=x^2$, that is just the boundary of the region of integration, so saying $(r \cos \theta)^2=r \sin \theta$ is not correct.  The other is that the region of integration is beyond the parabola (draw a picture), so $r$ should range from the solution to $x^2=x \sin \theta$ to the edge of the square which is at $r=\frac 1{\cos \theta}$  It should be 
$$\int_0^{\frac\pi4} d\theta \int_{\sin \theta}^{\frac 1{\cos \theta}} f(r \cos\theta, r \sin\theta) rdr$$

Comment: Given any fixed $\theta$, $r$ varies from $\sec\theta\tan\theta$ to $\frac 1{\cos \theta}$ because it seems to me from the picture that any ray through the origin that makes an angle $\theta \in [0,\frac \pi 4)$ with positive x axis intersects the parabola $y=x^2$. So  I think that the limits for $r$ should be from $\sec\theta\tan \theta$ to $\frac 1{\cos\theta}$. Can you please let me know what I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Just went too fast here. The equation should be $r^2\cos^2\theta = r\sin\theta$. I also think that using $x$ in place of $r$ is what led to this horrid mistake.

Comment: @Koro: your comment looks correct to me. The limits should be from $\tan(\theta)\sec(\theta)$ to $\sec(\theta)$.